# How to detect when the mouse is moving outside the window?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'd like to detect the mouse move event when it's moving outside the window by using MFC. I have used `OnNcMouseMove()` but it only detects the mouse move event when it's moving to the non-client area, not outside the window. So how can I do to detect while the mouse is moving outside the window?

Comment: If you only need to know, when the mouse leaves your window, you can use [WM_MOUSELEAVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645615.aspx). If you need to continuously monitor mouse movement outside your window, you'll have to go with [SetCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262.aspx) instead.

Comment: Is it possible to get the point coordinates of mouse when the mouse is outside the window?

Comment: If you've set up a mouse capture, you continue to receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages, even when the mouse cursor is outside your window. If you need to query the cursor position at a certain time, you can call [GetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390.aspx). And if you happen to be in a message handler, I believe you can call [GetMessagePos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938.aspx) to retrieve the cursor position  at the time the message was generated. It largely depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was set up a 100ms timer that calls `GetCursorPos()`.  You can tweak that timer value to make it higher resolution if needed, but for my specific UI need, 100ms was good enough - it dumped (x,y) coordinates to a status bar.

Comment: Like all approaches based on sampling, it doesn't account for events that happen in between the sampling points. If the mouse leaves the window, but enters it before you query for the next sample, you have missed the equivalent of a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message. This doesn't happen with `TrackMouseEvent`. I don't know if this is important to the OP, but without knowing, this answer is to be taken with a grain of salt.